# excel conditional formatting AND isnumber

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003

I'm trying to get my format sentence to work, but it just won't

I want to format the cell green if the cell is greater than the cell before it (and that cell contains a number)

I'm trying:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1))>INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())) AND ISNUMBER(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1)))
```

I added the and because some cells with text next before them got red. It works without the AND ISNumber part

[image]

Comment: Why not something like this? `=AND(ISNUMBER($A$1),$A$2>$A$1)` This will format the Cell `A2` green if cell `A1` is a number and `A2>A1`

Comment: I'll assume that you missed my comment by mistake?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I'm sorry, I don't see how that's different from Peter's suggestiion, only the arguments are switched, and the values are absolute and not dynamic

Comment: I was assuming (based on your question) that there was only one cell? I see your screenshot now and understood that there is a dynamic range involved :)

Comment: SiddharthRout - that's definitely what I want, only with dynamic cells

Comment: See my answer below. If you remove the "$" then it becomes dynamic.

Comment: Will it apply to all the cells in a pivot table even if the table expands beyond the range I have selected to start with?

Comment: May I see how your pivot looks so that I can test it first before commenting?

Comment: Ok after testing it on several pivots, I realized that the "Applies To" in conditional formatting remains absolute. So when the pivot rows expand all you have to do is to use the format painter to simply copy the CF to the rest of the cells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your above screenshot you can do this

[image]

Comment: Coming from the formula king, I take it as a huge compliment, barry :)

Comment: +1 with no doubts @Sid! Your answers with such nice screens make me weep often, since my team newcomers don't get the clue that 1 simple pic is 100000 times better than 1000 long explanation)))

Comment: And it actually will work in the pivot table if you just tick the "apply to all data fields"

Answer (score 1):

You simply use `AND` in wrong way - arguments should be listed separated by commas:

`=AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1))>INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),ISNUMBER(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1))))`

Comment: can you think of any reason the formatting would not be applied if they are numbers? I changed it and got no error, but not the aprropriate formatting either

Comment: If entered in the cell, this formula gives a `circular reference` error. Perhaps Excel logic is a bit different than ours) anyway, could you please share manually colored sample - i think there's more simple way to conditionally color it?

Comment: the problem is that it is applied to a pivottable, so it really has to be conditional and non-absolute, because the contents can change, but I'll see if I can get something shareable

Comment: Just color the sample - only relative cells position matters